# SharePoint 2010 migration from on Prem to AWS

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, migration, aws

In AWS, there is a feature where we can take the VM Snap and deploy that snap in AWS.

While doing so, IP address and domain will be changed, When all the VM's (SharePoint App servers and DB Server) are deployed, the SharePoint applications will come up?

Our SharePoint applications has Nintex workflows.

What are the do's and don't for such approaches?

What are the check point during this approach?

Are there any better approaches?

Answer (score 5):

The approach for this scenario is: don't. None of what you're suggesting is supported.

Instead, build a new farm and restore the Content Databases/Service Application databases.

Answer (score 3):

None of your approach is supported. You have to perform a DR for to move it to AWS.

- Create and configure the new SharePoint farm in AWS, make sure same build number and same set of customization & 3rd party tools installed in AWS farm.
- Now you can do two things.

  1. Either restore the content database from on prem to AWS.Make sure all services application created and configured in AWS
  2. Or you can perform a full back from on prem and restore it to AWS farm.
- Now test whats work and what's not. Fix all the issues and don the final migration.